# Monitor Showing White Lines after Removing RAM

Tags: boot, memory, motherboard

I had 2 2GB RAM sticks I took out of my computer because I borrowed them from somebody else.

So I took them out, and replaced them with 2 512MB ram sticks (these were originally in those slots).

I already had 1GB of RAM inside the computer, so I didn't think it would be much of an issue.

But when I started my computer up again (HP DC5100 MT), there are these white vertical lines all over the hp logo screen. Instead of booting into the OS, it just stays on this screen for about 3 minutes, then beeps one time and goes to a black screen where it tells me Error.

It says that this error is usually when the computer detects a removal of ram (this is true, I went from 5gb total with the 2, 2gb ram sticks, to 2 GB total with the 2 512mb ram sticks and the 1GB total in the other slots).

But it also said if this problem persists, make sure the RAM is plugged in properly.

So I press F1 to save changes, but my keyboard fails to respond. So I'm stuck on that screen. I pressed F1 but nothing happened. I'm not sure why its doing this. I've already restarted it 2 times, and replugged power supply, VGA cable to both monitor and tower.

How can I resolve this?

Answer (score 0):

You can press and hold the power button until it stops running. (That's the way to power off a PC when it cannot shut down normally.) After powering off (fans not running anymore), you can replug the RAM again, make sure it contacts well with the slots. Actually you can check the pins of the RAM, after long time lay aside, it might be oxidized or get moldy. You can use pencil to daub the pins. (Only be careful not to connect different pins with that.)

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like the RAM is not plugged in correctly

OR

As in the answer, check for dull or corroded contacts.  My preference is to use a pencil eraser to clean the contacts.

BE CAREFUL NOT TO HANDLE THE CONTACTS OR YOU MAY DAMAGE THE ICs

You can also swap the ram sticks to see if the fault changes, if so then one of the sticks may be duff!

Good luck

Comment: Thanks for the answer! Apparently the ram was just plugged in wrong. But i did use the pencil eraser to clean the contacts :D                                                 p.s: how to mark question as solved?